# Kafka connect raised an error: ERROR Error converting event to JSON

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

This is the `docker-compose.yml` (This the code is the snippet of the compose file (just `kafka`, `kafka`, `connect` and `redis`) from this [repo](https://github.com/udacity/nd029-c2-apache-spark-and-spark-streaming-starter/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml)):

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.6
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    depends_on:
      - "zookeeper"
 
  connect:
    image: gcr.io/simulation-images/kafka-connect-redis-source
    ports:
    - "8083:8083"
    - "5005:5005"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:19092"
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "connect"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-config"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-offset"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "connect-status"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_DEBUG: "y"
      DEBUG_SUSPEND_FLAG: "y"
      CLASSPATH: "/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-redis-source/*"

    depends_on:
    - "kafka"
    - "redis"
```

- `docker ps`:

```
=> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                            PORTS                                                                                            NAMES
c9c0c942d956   gcr.io/simulation-images/kafka-connect-redis-source   "/bin/sh -c 'connect…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp, :::5005->5005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, :::8083->8083/tcp, 9092/tcp   connect_1
dc94eb723e93   confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1                           "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes                      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, :::9092->9092/tcp                                                        kafka_1
c030c3be44e3   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1                       "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes                      2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, :::2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp                                    zookeeper_1
b7f2807280b1   redis:6.0.6                                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes                      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp                                                        redis_1
```

- `connect` service keep raising errors (It kept restarting):

```
connect_1    | [2021-12-07 22:42:29,455] ERROR Error converting event to JSON (org.apache.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSourceTask:102)
connect_1    | com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.moilioncircle.redis.replicator.event.PreRdbSyncEvent and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:404)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:4094)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3404)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSourceTask.getSourceRecord(RedisSourceTask.java:99)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSourceTask.poll(RedisSourceTask.java:77)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:272)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:239)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
connect_1    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
connect_1    | [2021-12-07 22:42:29,530] WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-redis-config-0] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {redis-server=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1077)
connect_1    | [2021-12-07 22:42:29,666] ERROR Error converting event to JSON (org.apache.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSourceTask:102)
connect_1    | com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.moilioncircle.redis.replicator.event.PreCommandSyncEvent and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:404)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:4094)
connect_1    |  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3404)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSourceTask.getSourceRecord(RedisSourceTask.java:99)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSourceTask.poll(RedisSourceTask.java:77)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:272)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:239)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
connect_1    |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
connect_1    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I know that the `connect` service is a sort of custom image so could be difficult to debug but I'd like to know whether these errors are related to Kafka environment variables(e.g. `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`) or it is a code level (e.g. java) problem.

Comment: There is no such package `org.apache.kafka.connect.redis` in Kafka, so where are you getting this from?

Comment: @OneCricketeer There is a repo link on the post. Please check that out please

Comment: That repo doesn't have any `RedisSourceTask.java` file, or Kafka Connect curl commands

Comment: I suggest following this issue - https://github.com/udacity/nd029-c2-apache-spark-and-spark-streaming-starter/issues/1

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for following up. The issue link is the one I raised already :). Btw, should I always have to launch `connect` service to print out the kafka stream data?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You can run `kafka-console-consumer` at any point, but of course you need data in some topic, and Kafka Connect is just one way to do that. You can use `kafka-console-producer` by itself and type whatever you want into it